Access image from the flutter root app in kotlin file
I have my kotlin file where I want to access an image, which is outside of android folder, in the root of flutter app.
 val imagePath = widgetData.getString("image", null)
    if (imagePath != null) {
        try {
            val fullImagePath = "assets/images/$imagePath"
            val assetInputStream = context.assets.open(fullImagePath)
            val assetBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(assetInputStream)
            setImageViewBitmap(R.id.backgroundImage, assetBitmap)
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            Log.e("CustomHomeView", "Error loading image: $e")
        }
    } 

That's how I want to access it.
But that what I got
Error loading image: java.io.FileNotFoundException: assets/images/fog_drizzle.webp
Any ideas how can I use my flutter image in kotlin CustomHomeView class? Thanks in advance

See https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/assets/assets-and-images#sharing-assets-with-the-underlying-platform.

@user18309290 it doesn't help
